# Upgrade gson dependency from 2.7 to 2.8 fails

Tags: android-studio, gradle, gson

I saw that a new version of Gson came out, so I decided to point to it.
I switched from

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8'
```

however gradle fails to locate 2.8 even though it worked with 2.7 fine. Maven central repository has had 2.7 for a long time

Answer (score 1):

While

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

worked, to import gson 2.8 you need

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

(with the `.0` at the end)